# Very Noob Question: How to connect Seeeduino Xiao to CR2032 battery holder with switch?

Tags: microcontroller, arduino, batteries, samd21

I am planning on soldering together a seeeduino xiao along with an adafruit 20mm Coin Cell Breakout w/On-Off Switch for use in a portable trinket to inject code. Problem is, I've never really done anything with micro-controllers or electronics though.

This is probably an easy answer for someone with experience.

Here are the 2 pinouts that I could find:
[image: Seeeduino Xiao]

[image: Battery Holder]

FYI: I already have a breadboard and soldering iron, so don't worry about that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Coin cells have a high series resistance like 1k+ depending on size, so read specs to estimate voltage drop.

The gecko M0 CPU’s operate at about “ 114 μA/MHz” so 32kHz would be low current but 24MHz would kill the battery.

Therefore consider a much larger battery.

Comment: Thanks for the reply! Assuming that the battery breakout board could be directly soldered to the seeeduino, what pins should be connected? Also the battery should work fine with the arduino I have seen it used with other SAMD21 boards

Comment: What’s the point if you specify 24MHz that would kill the battery?

Comment: I'm new so I honestly don't know. Your answer makes sense and the guide I was looking at is outdated so you are probably right. Thanks for helping me!